# Open last used folder in finder

Tags: macos, finder

Often I find that I want to open the previous or last folder that I worked with in finder. Say I'm saving something to a folder from my camera, I then go to gmail and click attach, it would be great if there was a "previous" or "last folder" button that takes me to where the photos are. Am I missing something, is there a hidden OSX feature that does this?

Comment: You mean something like **Go**-> **Recent Folders** in Finder menu bar?

Comment: Yes. It seems I just had my eyes closed, when you click on the folder name in the file dialog, the drop down shows a list of recent places at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "last folder" option can be found under **Go** -> **Recent Folders** Finder menu. There's a list of recent folders opened in Finder not just the "last folder".

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if one wants to map a *specific folder* to a Keyboard Shortcut, this can also be done.

#### From System Preferences

- Select **Keyboard**
- Select the **Shortcuts** tab
- In the Left Pane select **App Shortcuts**
- Click the Plus Button
- From the *All Applications** Drop-down, select **Finder**
- As long as you have the desired folder in the Recent Folders menu, type in the name of the folder EXACTLY as it is named in the **Menu Title** box
- Map it with a Key combination

Now, as long as Finder is the frontmost application, your shortcut will bring up the desired folder.

[image: Keyboard shortcut]

Comment: Interesting, would be cool if you could map a keyboard shortcut to "last folder". Sort of like the graphical equivalent of doing "cd -" in the terminal. Although "cd -" doesn't work in a new tab, it results in "OLDPWD not set"

Comment: Clever! Note that this will only work as long as the folder is in your Recent Folders list. If it gets bumped off the list you'll have to first open it another way, make the window inactive (now it's in the Recent Folders list), _and then open the Recent Folders list_ (showing the list triggers Finder to reassign the shortcut)